# Angular: ERROR in Cannot assign to a reference or variable

Tags: angular

as many I'm getting **ERROR in Cannot assign to a reference or variable!** when building --prod.
I would be happy to fix, but I'm just getting this message without any reference to my code.

I also tried to build `ng build --prod --verbose=true`, but I'm still stuck because I don't know where to search into my code.
Is there any options to get the full compile details steps ?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide screenshot or more information... We can't help you this way

Comment: It can occur for many possible reasons. say for "component and template used same variable names" or "model name can be overlapped" etc. so please share some screenshots of errors or what have you tried so far !

Comment: provide some more information.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I know that it can occured from diffrente reasons, but at least I'm expecting an information from the compiler about the module/file/etc. origin of the issue. I've thousands lines of codes. No error while only ng serve. Sorry no screenshot to provide. Just this message error after ng build --prod. This is why I'm expecting a way to get details from buiding process

Answer (score 1):

So, no way to get details about the source of the error message. The only option consists on isolate modules by exluding others (cf tsconfig.app.json), and proceed step-by-step by adding module per module in order to identify the root cause. 
Surprised to see that this kind of error finaly hides few others which appeared after fixing the first one.